Short story about a late night feline meeting
I'm trying to find a story I read once about a late night cat meeting. Cats from all over this city are called somehow to sneak out at night for this gathering. I think in the story you're following 1 or 2 house cats as they are called to attend this gathering. When they get there, it is a Siamese cat, I think, that is speaking about how humans took her kittens away from her and when we're not taking kittens away we have convinced our cats to be cute little creatures we keep as we like. It maybe sounds hokey but its well written and an incredibly poignant speech. But ultimately the Siamese reminds them all that they are all fiercesome beasts that demand respect or else! I think as the story ends the original cat(s), upon returning home decides what they will do with these new realizations of their true feline power.

Similar but possibly a hit - Neil Gaiman's "Dream of 1,000 Cats" from Sandman?

This sounds like it might be The Sandman #18, A Dream of a Thousand Cats, by Neil Gaiman, from August, 1990.  It has been collected in Sandman, Volume 3, Dream Country.
I've not read it, but the story is told, in animated form, on the TV series.
From https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Sandman_Vol_2_18:

Don and his young wife head to bed, leaving their new kitten to rest in his bed. After they have gone, the kitten receives a visitor, a brown cat announcing an event to be hosted by a certain female cat of renown. They prowl their way to an overgrown grave yard, picking up others on their way until a gathering of many cats waits for the speaker.
The speaker reveals herself finally; a pure bred Blue-Point Siamese. She explains that she once believed that she was free in her life of cohabitation with humans. That was until she met a tomcat who impregnated her, and she later had kittens. Her owners were displeased by this, and eventually, the man took the kittens and drowned them all in a lake. Confused and horrified, the cat lapsed into dream.



Yes that's it! A thousand thanks. I didn't read this as a comic though. It had to be in some short story collection.

@user174442 - I don't believe it's been adapted into a prose story. It was part of the Sandman full-cast audiobook though

It was the Sandman TV series! How I thought I read it instead???You are all my heroes for helping solve this mystery. Thank You!

@user174442 Please mark the answer as accepted then. You just have to click on the tick on its left.
